# PHP7. Не понятен принцип работы метода getTrace в классе Exception

Tags: php, исключения

Помогите разобраться с исключениями. Результатом такого кода будет пустой массив:

```
function truct()
{
    return false;
}

try {
    $a = truct();
    if (!$a) {
        throw new Exception('iorgiog', 2324);
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e->getTrace());
}
```

А результат выполнения такого кода уже массив с данными:

```
function truct()
{
    throw new Exception('iorgiog', 2324);
}

try {
    truct();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e->getTrace());
}
```

По какой причине первый вариант кода выбрасывает пустой массив? Проверял методы getMessage и getCode - они отрабатывают нормально.

Comment: Потому что стек вызовов собственно пуст?

Comment: У вас экзепшн вылетает в методе, в котором вы его и ловите, потому трейса нету

Comment: и чего ответом не оформите?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам необходимо разобраться с тем, как устроен [стек вызовов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2) - это должно добавить понимания.

Но если в двух словах, то в первом случае порядок действий таков:

```
1. Начало работы
   - стек пустой: []
2. вызвана функция "truct";
   - в стек добавляется "truct": [truct]
3. завершена работа функции "truct";
   - из стека удаляется "truct": []
4. в блоке "try" генерируется исключение и управление переходит секции "catch"
   - стек пустой: []
```

Во втором же случае всё несколько иначе:

```
1. Начало работы
  - стек пустой: []
2. в блоке "try" вызвана функция "truct";
   - в стек добавляется "truct": [truct]
3. генерируется исключение и управление переходит секции "catch"
   - стек остаётся неизменным: [truct]
```